# Constructing a morphism by defining it on generalized elements

Tags: logic, category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category, and let $A$ and $B$ be objects in that category. It is clear that given a morphism $f:A\to B$, we know what $f$ does on generalized elements $e:A'\to A$, since this is just done by composing with $f$. However, I was wondering if there is always a converse construction. Or, if there are any known constraints on when such a converse construction can be made. That is, can we define a morphism $f:A\to B$, given that we know how generalized elements are mapped to $B$. That is, we know $e:A'\to A$ and we 'know' $f\circ a:A'\to B$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a great question ! The answer is yes, that's essentially the statement of the *Yoneda lemma*.

It says more specifically that given a natural transformation $\eta : \hom(-,A)\to \hom(-,B)$ (that is, a way to assign a generalized element of $B$ to a generalized element of $A$ in a coherent fashion), there is a unique morphism $f: A\to B$ such that $\eta (g) = f\circ g$ for all $g: X\to A$ generalized element.

The proof is quite easy actually : if you know how to assign generalized elements of $B$ to generalized elements of $A$, just look at "the universal generalized element of $A$" : $id_A: A\to A$. Then you get $\eta_A(id_A) : A\to B$ and that's exactly your $f$ (and the fact that this $f$ works for everyone comes from the naturality of $\eta$)

Comment: Perfect! Blessed be Yoneda! Every category theory related problem turns out to be solved by the Yoneda lemma it seems. So this also gives us that this only works if the map from generalized elements of $A$ to generalized elements of $B$ is natural right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it  !

Comment: Just to tie together the relevant terminology: The "known constraints" asked for in the question are precisely the "in a coherent fashion" mentioned parenthetically in this answer and the "natural" mentioned in @EBP's comment here.